# What am i supposed to Import? Hello World Program

Tags: java, jogl

Im completely new to Jogl and Java and what am i supposed to Import in this Hello world program? Thanks!

```
public class HelloWorld
{ // open HelloWorld

    public static void main (String args[])
    { // open main
        try
        { // open try
            System.loadLibrary("jogl");
            System.out.println("Hello World! (The native libraries are installed.)");
        } // close try
        catch (Exception e) // all try's need a catch
        { } // even if the catch does nothing
    } // close main

} // close HelloWorld
```

Comment: What is the program supposed to do? As it is, your current example does not need any imports.

Answer (score 2):

For *that* particular code, I don't think you need to import anything. The only package you use is `System` which is already available to you.

If you want to do more complicated stuff, you'll probably need, at a minimum:

```
import net.java.games.jogl.*
```

although you could no doubt exert a finer-grained control than that, by importing specific stuff.

Comment: @user1204570: Have you added the JOGL libraries to your build path?

Comment: O gosh NO i didnt :x... How do i do it on Eclipse?

Comment: Try this: http://www.wikihow.com/Add-JARs-to-Project-Build-Paths-in-Eclipse-%28Java%29

Answer (score 0):

If you are not going to do anything other than print that string then no need for other imports. Importing is only necessary if your using it in your program like BufferedReader, etc.